# getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

am using a Bluetooth  printer in my flutter project and am receiving this error
getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
how i can fix it
thank you

i have tried to give it all the the administration permissions for Bluetooth